# Explain use of levels in winston logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, npm, winston

Hey i am using this winston logger,
kindly explain use of level inside the transports, what will happen if i use logger with info while logging, do i have to use debug while i log my data.

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
  new (winston.transports.Console)({
    level: 'debug',
    json: true
  }),
  new (winston.transports.File)({
    name: 'order_check',
    filename: './logs/order_check.log',
    level: 'debug'
  })
]
});
logger.log("info","request body");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The level inside your transport indiciates the *minimum* logging level that transport will "listen out for"

From the documentation:
https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#logging-levels

> Each level is given a specific integer priority. The higher the priority the more important the message is considered to be

```
{ error: 0, warn: 1, info: 2, verbose: 3, debug: 4, silly: 5 }
```

So, in your example, your transports are configured for `debug: 4`

This means it will log levels

- 4 (debug)
- 3 (verbose)
- 2 (info)
- 1 (warn)
- 0 (error)

A good use case for this would be to set one transport (`Console`, for example) to debug and your other to info.

This would output all `debug` information to the console, but log only `info` to file, preventing log file clutter.

Comment: logger.log("info","request body");
what is the meaning of info inside this function? is this info level and transport level related ?

Comment: this means you're logging an 'info' related message - in your example, it will log to both transports, since you've set them to log debug and higher. There's nothing transport related in `logger.log("info","request body");` - only log level, and message

Comment: is 0 the highest level ?

Comment: Thanx Alex for the help.

Comment: do you want me to set logger.log("info","request body"); and transports.console level to debug right  and then check the logs ?

Comment: not sure I understand... `logger.log` is the call you make when you want to log something. If transports.console level is debug, it will log to the console, even when using `logger.log("info`

Answer (score 0):

the logging level reflects the importance of the logging message
for example, debug is used for non important messages, used for debugging only

info is used for something more important

if you set the logging level to debug then the logs will show debug and info messages (and higher)

if you set the logging level to info then the logs will show only info messages (and higher) - you wont see the debug messages - this helps to avoid clutter in the logs and prevents too much info being shown in the logs in a production environment