# Winston log in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I can not seem to log in production mode using winston, my logger instance looks like

```js
export const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "debug",
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console({ format })]
});
```

I tried to log in prod mode like

```js
logger.log({ 
  level: "debug", // tried "info" too
  message: "something"
})
```

Can I do something in my caller to log in prod mode?

Comment: Take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809486/explain-use-of-levels-in-winston-logger). Basically you are setting the highest level for your production logs, so only logs with level "error" will show on console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain use of levels in winston logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809486/explain-use-of-levels-in-winston-logger)